# JSTL Bug in function endsWith?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, ends-with

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn"%>

<c:set var="some" value="abcdef"/>
${fn:endsWith(some, 'ef')}
```

returns true

```
<c:set var="some" value="abcdefef"/>
${fn:endsWith(some, 'ef')}
```

returns false

It looks like the function `endsWith` checks the string from its begining instead of from its end.
If the string from second argument appers in the first argument not only at the its end, then the function returns false.

Comment: What server did you use to test it? Maybe implementation of other servers is not buggy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes, their is a bug in jstl

```
public static boolean endsWith(String input, String substring)
    {
        if (input == null)
            input = "";
        if (substring == null)
            substring = "";
        int index = input.indexOf(substring);
        if (index == -1)
            return false;
        if (index == 0 && substring.length() == 0)
            return true;
        return (index == input.length() - substring.length());
}
```

it is using indexof instead of endsWith of String

Comment: Instead of `${endsWith(input, substring)}`, here's the rather verbose alternative I am using `${fn:substring(input, fn:length(input)-fn:length(substring), fn:length(input)) == substring}`

Comment: Better yet, write a custom function replacing `indexOf()` with `lastIndexOf()`

Comment: Does exist/have you got a reference to some bugtracker mentioning this bug?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the JSTL JAR files with the Apache version instead, http://tomcat.apache.org/taglibs/standard/.  It fixes the same problem for me.